# How to redirect /user to /user/UID, for logged in users?

Tags: users, redirection

I run a [social movement community site](http://effectivealtruismhub.com/user/profiles), which features links to [the '/user' page](http://effectivealtruismhub.com/user), which either shows people [the login/registration page](http://effectivealtruismhub.com/user), or shows them their user account if they're logged in. If people are logged in, how can I make these links to /user redirect to /user/UID ? (E.g. if I'm the one logged in, I'd like to redirect my visits to http://effectivealtruismhub.com/user to http://effectivealtruismhub.com/user/1 - currently it shows me my user page, but just shows http://effectivealtruismhub.com/user in the address bar.)

This is a valuable feature because people benefit from seeing the URL of their user page, as on this community site and others they'll want to share it with people.

Answer (score 1):

If you were handcoding this, you would create a menu path using hook_menu, with %uid as the second parameter. And the `page_callback` value of the menu item would be the function rendering the user page. You will then use `hook_user_login` to set the redirect rule.

If you were doing this using contrib modules, I suggest you looking into profile2, it comes with a built in functionality where each user has their own profile page.

**edited:**
The last sentence on your question, makes me led to think that the user/%uid path needs to be accessible users/visitors other than the owner. So let's here is how you would do it.

1. Create your custom module, let's call it `ea_custom` for the sake of
   this example.
2. Add hook_menu and page_callback to your ea_custom.module and register the path for the individual user page.

   /*** Implements hook_menu ***/
   function ea_custom_menu() {
     $items['users/%user'] = array( //the %user will be used as argument for the page callback
       'title' => t('User Profile'),
       'page callback' => 'ea_custom_render_userpage',
       'page arguments' => array(1), //zero base array. This tells hook menu to first load user with the specified uid specified by %user parameter.
       'access callback' => 'user_access', //so non-onwer can also view it
       'access arguments' => array('access content'),
     );
     return $items;
   }

   /**** page callback for users/%user ****/
   function ea_custom_render_userpage($user) {
      //you now have accessed to the user object
      drupal_set_message('

   ```
   ' . print_r($user, TRUE) . '
   ```

   ');

   //assemble your output using the values inside $user object
      $output = $user->uid; //etc.. etc...

   return $output;
   }

**Additional notes:** you can use different methods to get values from entity objects such as user and node. I would recommend you to check `entity_metadata_wrapper` for one. Also, instead of using %user, to get user object, you could opt to use %profile2, since you have that module installed, and it will allows you access to fields you have attached to profile type.

wow, I can't seem to format this properly. Here is the paste bin: http://pastebin.com/kiv6GfPN

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the first option. I'm using profile2, but it still has the described issue: if you visit http://effectivealtruismhub.com/user you only see http://effectivealtruismhub.com/user in the address bar.

Comment: Alas I need some help understanding the 1st option. I don't know what you mean by "with %uid as the second parameter" or "use hook_user_login to set the redirect rule". Here's my code so far, how would I extend it? It's at http://pastebin.com/mK6cUpFW and pasted here: 

`<?php function ea_hub_support_menu() { $items['user/redirect'] = array( 'page callback' => 'WHAT?'        );  return $items; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module **Login Destination**, Website: [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination)

Once there you can create your the action destination after login and inside there create a code in PHP:

```
<?php
  global $user;
  return  "user/".$user->uid;
?>
```

That can work for what you need, let me know !

Comment: This doesn't sound like it gives me a page I can link to for all users to take them to /user/UID

Comment: Login Destination will redirect to whatever page you need ... if you do that PHP Code, that will redirect to your website plus that link after you log in. Example :  http://effectivealtruismhub.com/user/".$user->uid

Isn't that what your looking for?

Comment: No, I want to redirect the URL /user to /user/UID, for logged in users. At the very least, I want to be able to have a link - like /user - which will show the page of whatever user is logged in, and have that link then show /user/UID in the address bar.